# Characters do not display properly in terminal (st)

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, locale, character-encoding

When typing German umlauts (`ä`,`ö`,`ü`) into the terminal (I am using st on Arch Linux, `$XTERM` is `st-256color`), it displays only `<ffffffff>`. Locale seems to be set properly.

Output of `locale` is

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=de-DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=de-DE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

In `locale.conf` I only set

```
LANG="de-DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de-DE.UTF-8"
```

In `locale.gen` I uncommented `de-DE.UTF-8`. Where could it go wrong?

Comment: After editing `locale.gen`, did you also run the `locale-gen` command?

Comment: Yes, output is ```Generating locales...
  de_DE.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  zh_CN.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual locale names have an *underscore* between the language code and the country code, i.e. your `locale.conf` should be:

```
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Currently, you have minus signs (`-`) instead of underscores (`_`). Since your locale specifications are not valid, the system is falling back to the POSIX locale and US-ASCII character set only.

The `LANG` variable sets the default for all the other locales, so just setting

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

is equivalent to setting all the category-specific `LC_*` locale variables to the same value, unless you override specific categories with any of the `LC_*` variables.

So if you set `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`, you should not need `LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8` since setting `LANG` already sets it as the new default for `LC_CTYPE`. However, if you don't like translated error messages and wish to keep them in English, you might want to set `LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8` to override the LANG value for the LC_MESSAGES category only.

The output of your `locale` command also reflects this: it shows all the category specific variables as set to the same (incorrect) value as your current `LANG` setting.

`LC_ALL` is a master override for all the locale settings: you'll most commonly see it with some pipelines that are parsing some command output that might be affected by localization. Prefixing such pipelines with `LC_ALL=POSIX` or `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` guarantee that the script writer needs to design the output parsing for that particular locale only, no matter which locale the user is using otherwise.